# how to create properties file android

Tags: android, app-config, configuration-files

I would like to create the config file on android application and I know
for Xcode we use plist, Dot net uses app.config but for android I
don't have an idea to create file.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for android application I found the way to create app.properties file, after already app.properties created it's easy to get data from .properties file. Example's below:

```
public void CreatePropertiesFile(Context context)
{
Properties prop = new Properties();
String propertiesPath = context.getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/app.properties";
try {
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(propertiesPath);
       prop.setProperty("HomeVersion", "0");
prop.setProperty("DatePlaySquare", "0");
prop.setProperty("CustomerID", "0");
prop.setProperty("DeviceToken", "0");
prop.setProperty("CurrentVersionMobile", "0");
prop.setProperty("Domain", "Megazy");
prop.setProperty("DownloadNewVersion","0");
       prop.store(out, null);
       out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
   System.err.println("Failed to open app.properties file");
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Aey.Sakon

Answer (score 3):

That good sir is possible by using [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: could you explain this a little more please?